# add css rule using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i got a css rule like this:

```
#imgwrapper {display: block;position: relative;width:auto;height:auto;}
```

so i got a hyperlink that when it's clicked, it should add a css rule to #imgwrapper like this:

```
#imgtarget, #imgwrapper img {cursor:crosshair;}
```

how should i do it??

i tried jquery .css() api but it aint working..

Comment: Can you post the code you tried that used `.css()`?

Comment: Please post an example of the code you have that isn't working.

Comment: did you try below code , is it working...

Comment: hi everyone, the reply from David Fells works.. earlier i did it wrongly by doing it this way: $('#imgtarget').css('cursor:crosshair');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [$.css() function](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('a.whatever').click(function() {
  $('#imgtarget').css('cursor' , 'crosshair');
  $('#imgwrapper img').css('cursor', 'crosshair');
});
```

Comment: hey david, your solution works.. but now wat if i wanna remove these css properties??

Comment: hey david, i found the solution. sorry my bad.. what i did is to set the value to ''.. so ie: $('#imgtarget').css('cursor' , '');
  $('#imgwrapper img').css('cursor', '');

Answer (score 2):

the following code should work.

```
$('#imgwrapper').css('cursor','crosshair')
```