# Create a new (permenant) CSS style in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I want to create a new style, not just alter the style attribute of an element. Here's some example code to demonstrate the problem:

```
//Create 1st element
var element1 = $('<div />').text('element1').addClass('blue');
$('body').append(element1);

//Set some css for all elements with the blue class
$('.blue').css('background-color', 'blue');

//Create 2nd element, it won't have the css applied because it wasn't around when the css was set
var element2 = $('<div />').text('element2').addClass('blue');
$('body').append(element2);​
```

In the code above the 2nd element does not have the same style as the 1st. What I would like is to be able to set the css on a className for all future elements.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YenN4/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add to a css class using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877440/add-to-a-css-class-using-jquery)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could create a new stylesheet and append this to the head:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .blue{ background-color:blue;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YenN4/2/

Answer (score 5):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T6KEW/

```
$('<style>').text('.blue { background: blue }').appendTo('head');

$('<div>').text('element1').addClass('blue').appendTo('body');
$('<div>').text('element2').addClass('blue').appendTo('body');​
```