# Append a class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add css rule using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846900/add-css-rule-using-jquery)

I want to add a second class to a DIV dynamically. I have a variable that is doing this:

```
var headerDIV = $("<div>", { "class": "modal-header" }).appendTo($(this.dialog));
```

this code is inside a function, now I want to create a new variable that contains a css class and I want to add it only with a name like this:

```
    var headerDIV = $("<div>", { "class": "modal-header " + 'customClass' }).appendTo($(this.dialog));
```

My customClass will be like this:

```
var customClass = { 'background-color': '#00609a', 'color': 'white' };
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: It seems you want to add CSS rules to an element, not a class. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/css/.

Comment: .css(customClass) will work